# In Linux: why can't an alias be used in a one-line stream of cshell commands?

Tags: linux, alias, csh

Let's say I have a cshell script that sets an alias.
Then I want to run the alias....

```
test.csh
alias runit "source runit.csh"

runit.csh
echo "Im Running it"
```

This works fine if I...

```
source test.csh
runit
```

I get the "Im Running it"

But if I...

```
source test.csh; runit
```

I get "runit: Command not found."

Why is that ?

Comment: That is just one of many limitations of the `csh`. The interpreter has scanned the whole line of intput (including `; runit`), has set itself up, and the `alias` isn't in the environment at that time. You have to run the cmds on separate .lines. Maybe an `eval` in there might get you something. The same may be true for newer shells, but I don't have time to test right now. Good luck.

Comment: Thank You Shelter for the explanation !